# From a sparse to dense representation of matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a list of vectors in python with 3 values with represent a sparse matrix. In fact the first values are the indexes of a 2d array (30 is the max value for the first index s and 9 the max value for the second index) and the third elements is the values of the matrix. How can I calculate the denserepresantation of the  matrix 30x9 from that list? My data has the following structure:

```
> [1, 1, 4], 
  [1, 4, 2], 
  [1, 6, 1], 
  [1, 8, 5], 
   ....
  [31, 9, 6], 
  ...
```

I want a matrix with rows to be from 1-31 and columns index to be from 1-9 and the values of the matrix to be the third value of the vectors. In the end I want to perform NMF in the dataset [found here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
vectors = [[1,1,2],[2,4,6],[31,2,8]]

tab=[[0 for col in range(9)] for row in range(31)]
for x in vectors:
    tab[x[0]-1][x[1]-1] = x[2]
print tab
```

Comment: With your answer I have 10 columns instead of 9 and the first column is zero. But if I change range to 9 I am getting errors.